# Forward declaration for recursive data structure

Tags: c++, recursion, data-structures

Way back when I was writing Delphi, there was a `TStringList` which was basically a map of strings to Delphi's generic `TObject`. Using this structure, I could easily make a recursive, hierarchical structure by placing another `TStringList` against one of the string keys:

```
ParentStringList["somekey"] = "just a string value";
ParentStringList["anotherkey"] = SomeChildStringList;
```

Question is, how do I achieve the same thing in C++?

What I have at the moment is:

```
typedef boost::variant< std::string, my_dictionary > my_variant;
typedef std::map < std::string, my_variant > my_dictionary;
```

... which is clearly circular.

Can I do this without wrapping things in structs (which I can forward declare), or without using pointers (which the compiler knows the size of)?

Comment: `struct X { X x; };` -- no.

Comment: Your aversion against pointers is a very good attitude in C++, but a bit overblown in this particular case. I guess a Delphi implementation will also solve this problem with pointers internally. If I were you, I'd use a pointer-based solution (probably with `std::unique_ptr`) and wrap everything nicely in a class with a completely pointer-free interface.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [Boost.Variant documentation](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_57_0/doc/html/variant/tutorial.html#variant.tutorial.recursive) covers this exact case. You can't do it without using pointers or some other similar wrapper.

Answer (score 0):

This approach could work:

```
struct my_variant;
typedef map<string,my_variant> my_dict;
struct my_variant: variant<string, my_dict>
{};
```

There are a few issues with it though:

- This requires containers (`std::map` specifically) that allow template arguments that are not fully defined. Using C++98, this is explicitly forbidden, I'm not sure if this was lifted in later C++ versions.
- Publicly deriving from containers is not usually a good idea, please research the reasons for that yourself and how they apply to your program. Using containment instead of derivation would be a safer alternative, or the middle way of private derivation, but that breaks the useful IS-A relationship that this approach provides.

Comment: Seems like gcc-12 / C++20 has finally resolved the issue. Recursive w/o pointers compiles fine.

gcc-11.2 (latest stable at the moment of this writing) still fails.

Answer (score -2):

Try using [vectors](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/vector/vector/). I've used them before as internal representations of an external database within my program as a data structure.

Comment: This is incorrect – `std::vector` is not guaranteed to allow recursive data structures (although in practice all sane implementations support it). But worse, that doesn’t help OP because they want to use  *dynamic* value types.

Comment: Do you mean arbitrary data types? Please explain "dynamic"?

Comment: By “dynamic” I mean what’s usually meant by “dynamic type”, i.e. that the actual type being used is only known at runtime, not yet at compile time. That’s not the same as “arbitrary” because the type can still be statically constrained to a well-defined subset of all possible types.

Comment: I still believe vectors would be applicable here. Accessing two different vectors in the same loop would retain the functionality of accessing the data structure with different types. As for runtime-known types, there must be another way, and I confess I have no idea how to implement such dynamic data types.